# Get index of select option in optgroup

Tags: javascript

If I have an option list like the below:

```
<select name="optionList" id="optionList"> 
    <optgroup label="optgroup1"> 
        <option value="1">1</option> 
        <option value="2">2</option> 
        <option value="3">3</option> 
        <option value="4">4</option> 
    </optgroup> 
    <optgroup label="optgroup2"> 
        <option value="5">5</option> 
        <option value="6">6</option> 
        <option value="7">7</option> 
        <option value="8">8</option> 
    </optgroup> 
</select>
```

I know I can access the selectedIndex using:

`document.getElementById('optionList').selectedIndex;`

If I use the above though the selected index of 5 will be 4, 6 will be 5, 7 will be 6, etc

How can I tell where a selected item in an optgroup is?

In summary I'd like to be able to query something and get back its position in the optgroup so that 5 would return 0, 6 would return 1 etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a slightly complex task, because there is no native way to do it. I'm going to answer according to current browser standards: it's possible to do it in older browsers, but it is more work.

```
var select = document.getElementById('optionList'), // the <select> element
    selectedIndex = select.selectedIndex, // 0-based index of which element in the <select> is selected
    selectedElement = select.options[selectedIndex], // DOM element selected
    optGroup = selectedElement.parentNode, // <optgroup> element
    optGroupOptions = optGroup.children, // <option> elements in the <optgroup>
    positionInOptGroup = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(optGroupOptions, selectedElement); // the selected <option>'s position in the <optgroup>
```

[(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/74Sw4/1/)

Note that this will not work if the browser does not support [`Element#children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) (i.e. IE <9). You will have to filter the `childNodes` collection into an array at test against that. Similarly, it requires `Array#indexOf`, which also didn't exist in IE <9.

Answer (score 1):

with pure javascript

```
var element = document.getElementById('optionList');
console.log(element.options[element.selectedIndex].parentNode.label);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery crossbrowser solution:

```
$('#optionList option:selected').index();
```

[preview](http://jsfiddle.net/tLz8g/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function indexOf(select) {
    var options = select.options;
    var selectedOption = options.item(select.selectedIndex);
    var nodes = selectedOption.parentNode.children;

    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
        if (nodes[i] === selectedOption) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

indexOf(document.getElementById('optionList'));
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/49R7k/1/

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question and implementations may have changed, but I found that simple jQuery solution within the selector change event, e.g.

```
$(document).on('change', ".cmilestoneTaskSelector", function(e) 
  {
  alert($(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).index());
   .....
```

Tested in both Firefox and Chrome.